# How to check if value has in array of data? NgIf

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I need to check if value exist in array of data.

gjhg = [ id, name ]

Comment: `!!training.id`? Or do you need to check if there's an actual existing value? Hard to tell with the information provided.

Comment: I need to check if there an actual existing value

Comment: Only to check if training.id id existing in any array of id-s

Comment: I would add a method in the component class that does the check for you, using array.find for example

Comment: can you provide me piece of code example ?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comment, this would be best suited for a method in the component controller, i.e.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  allowedIds = [1, 2, 12] // What I want to be allowed to show
  data = [
    {id: 1, value: 'whatever'},
    {id: 2, value: 'whatever2'},
    {id: 6, value: 'whatever3'},
    {id: 9, value: 'whatever4'},
    {id: 12, value: 'whatever5'},
  ] // Actual data

  idExists(id) {
    // Only return true if the supplied ID is in the allowedIds array
    return this.allowedIds.includes(id)
  }
}
```

```
<div *ngFor="let d of data">
    <pre *ngIf="idExists(d.id)">{{ d | json }}</pre>
</div>
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-swnjyx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach where we don't need to declare a dedicated function in ts file

This works when we need to check if the record has an id or not

```
<div *ngFor="let d of data">
    <pre *ngIf="d.id">{{ d | json }}</pre>
</div>
```

This works when we have a list of  allowedIds and only entries with allowed ids can be displayed

```
<div *ngFor="let d of data">
    <pre *ngIf=" allowedIds.includes(d.id )">{{ d | json }}</pre>
</div>
```

[stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-iw1zn9?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: It's more helpful to link to the stackblitz that shows the code, and include the code here.

Comment: @Phix, please find the stackblitz example here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9bupqm?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: The question was to only display something if the ID exists in an array, not sure what you mean here.

Comment: @Phix please let me know if the answer looks good after this edit.